# Communicate between Native Messaging Host and C# app

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a chrome extension that can communicate with a Native Messaging Host that I created in C#.

However, how can I communicate between the Native Messaging Host and a C# app. I think it will be via the Native Messaging Host input/output streams, but I haven't been able to find how to do this.

Comment: Here's a project using native-messaging and the host uses stdin/stdout and is written in C#: https://github.com/frederiksen/chrome-platform-bridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way of using Process.StandardInput because chrome launches the Native Messaging Host.

Instead I used WCF. Here is the code:

```
    private static object SyncRoot = new object();
    static string returnValue = null;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGetChromeString
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetString(string value);
    }

    public class CGetChromeString : IGetChromeString
    {
        public string GetString(string value)
        {
            OpenStandardStreamOut(value);
            // Wait until OpenStandardStreamIn() sets returnValue in the Main Thread
            lock (SyncRoot)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(SyncRoot);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CGetChromeString), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") }))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IGetChromeString), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "PipeReverse");

            host.Open();
            while (returnValue != "")
            {
                returnValue = OpenStandardStreamIn();
                // returnValue has been set, GetUrl can resume.
                lock (SyncRoot)
                {
                    Monitor.Pulse(SyncRoot);
                }
            }

            host.Close();
        }
    }

    static string OpenStandardStreamIn()
    {
        Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        stdin.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
        int length = 0;

        length = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

        string input = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            input += (char)stdin.ReadByte();
        }
        return input;
    }

    static void OpenStandardStreamOut(string stringData)
    {
        string msgdata = "{\"text\":\"" + stringData + "\"}";
        int DataLength = msgdata.Length;
        Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 0) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 8) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 16) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 24) & 0xFF));
        Console.Write(msgdata);
    }
```